# How to correctly return json to IE8 from ajax php script

Tags: php, ajax, json, internet-explorer

I am using this ajax file upload script, and all works well in firefox http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

But it does not work in IE8.

EDIT: Ok, i've narrowed down the problem.  In my php ajax response I do this

```
$result['table_1']='<b>text</b>';
echo json_encode($result);
```

The result I see in the IE developer tools looks like this

```
JOURNAL : [uploader] innerHTML = {"table_1":"<B>text&lt;\/b&gt;"}</B>
```

The end of the inner html got messed up, and the json got messed up with the correct ending tag somehow ending up outside the json??

I am using php 5.2

Comment: The quotes don't match. See `labelrow` and `label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a olution that works. This library works through an iframe, so to return text like

```
$result='<b id="1">text</b>';
```

I have to manually encode and decode the " myself because they get messed up in the iframe.
So the final php looks like this

```
$result['table_1']=htmlentities(str_replace('"','|',getRowHTML()));
echo json_encode($result);
```

And then to manually decode in the javascript looks like this

```
   function(id, fileName, responseJSON)
    {
      $('#table_1 tbody').html
      (
         //this line decodes responseJSON.table_1
         $("<div/>").html(responseJSON.table_1.replace(/\|/g,'"')).text()
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try validating your JSON response with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). On the other hand, if you've got PHP >= 5.3.0, you can use `json_last_error()` to verify what's causing PHP to fail on the encoding process.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem `Invalid JSON: {"text":"<H2>Update Complete&lt;\/H2&gt;"}</H2>` with ie and solved it by using 
<strike>http://www.captain.at/howto-php-urlencode-javascript-decodeURIComponent.php</strike>
(that site is no longer programming I found a similar function here [What is the equivalent of JavaScript's encodeURIcomponent in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734250/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-in-php)) on the PHP side

```
$response->text .= encodeURIComponent("<H2 class='action_result'>Update Complete.</H2>");
return json_encode($response);
```

and in the js I used

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
var response = jQuery.parseJSON (responseText);
$('#ajax_form_response')[0].innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(response.text);
}
```