# encodeURI() in PHP?

Tags: php, url

Is there some encodeURI() function in PHP that does not encode: `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`?

Comment: So, which characters *do* you want it to encode?

Comment: you may need to go custom here and decode back out the chars you'd like to keep, if that's a short list

Answer (score 31):

I'm using this now

```
function encodeURI($url) {
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI
    $unescaped = array(
        '%2D'=>'-','%5F'=>'_','%2E'=>'.','%21'=>'!', '%7E'=>'~',
        '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')'
    );
    $reserved = array(
        '%3B'=>';','%2C'=>',','%2F'=>'/','%3F'=>'?','%3A'=>':',
        '%40'=>'@','%26'=>'&','%3D'=>'=','%2B'=>'+','%24'=>'$'
    );
    $score = array(
        '%23'=>'#'
    );
    return strtr(rawurlencode($url), array_merge($reserved,$unescaped,$score));

}
```

It basically rawurlencodes everything, and then decodes a few things back (as Zanlok suggested in his comment). This should conform to the Mozilla specs of encodeURI.

And following MDN, 'if one wishes to follow the more recent RFC3986 for URLs', add

```
function fixedEncodeURI($url) {
    return strtr(encodeURI($url),array('%5B'=>'[', '%5D'=>']'));
}
```

Comment: You can add `'%5B'=>'[', '%5D'=>']'` to reserved chars to be match the RFC3986 (IPV6 brackets)

Comment: @mems, thanks for the suggestion. I'm following the MDN specs - I'll wait for those to be updated.

Answer (score 21):

Here's an alternate version based on [ECMA-262 spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description):

```
function encodeURI($uri)
{
    return preg_replace_callback("{[^0-9a-z_.!~*'();,/?:@&=+$#-]}i", function ($m) {
        return sprintf('%%%02X', ord($m[0]));
    }, $uri);
}
```