# PHP: fopen(UrlWithWhiteSpaces)

Tags: php, url, fopen

As you can see on the title, I am trying to  `fopen()` a Url with whitespaces. Other stackoverflow posts didn't help really, could it possibly be that they are outdated?
I have tried:

- urlencode
- rawurlencode

None of the above works , **`http://test.com/two - words.jpg`** this gives me:

- urlencode: `http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Ftwo+-+words.jpg`
- rawurlencode: `http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Ftwo%20-%20words.jpg`

When i am trying to clearly get **`http://test.com/two%20-%20words.jpg`** , which is what the browser shows when you type `http://test.com/two - words.jpg` and hit enter.

Which function do I have to use to make those conversions from `space` to `%20` , and **all**
 the other possible conversions i could need(which i can't think of any more, but i am pretty sure they exist, maybe on special symbols)  ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929584/encodeuri-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**:

```
$newUrl = preg_replace('/ /', '%20', 'http://test.com/two - words.jpg');

echo $newUrl;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
http://test.com/two%20-%20words.jpg
```

And alternatively **[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**:

```
$newUrl = str_replace(' ', '%20', 'http://test.com/two - words.jpg');
```

But more generally you will need to encode more than just the space. I made this function, if you don't want to use **[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)** or **[rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)**, this is what you are looking for:

```
function encodeURI($URI)
{
    return str_replace(array('%', '^', '+', '{', '[', '}', ']', '"', '|', '\\', '<', '>', ' '),
        array('%25', '%5E', '%2B', '%7B', '%5B', '%7D', '%5D', '%22', '%7C', '%5C', '%3C', '%3E', '%20'), $URI);
}
```

**example**

```
echo encodeURI('http://test.com/two - ["word<><s.jpg');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
http://test.com/two%20-%20%5B%22word%3C%3E%3Cs.jpg
```

Comment: hello again ! are you sure thats the only conversion i need ? im skeptical about it, i will however use this since i have no better option

Comment: Well that is what you've asked.

Comment: `and all the other possible conversions i could need`

Comment: regex instead of `str_replace`? Why the overhead?