# how to fix fopen unexpected 400 bad request error when url contains ghost word “- H”?

Tags: php, fopen, bad-request

everyone, I have a super werid problem:

I'm using php7.4 on ubuntu18.04, and I want to fetch my remote resource using `fopen`.

This is sample code:

```php
// That's say remote file name: "- h.zip"
fopen('http://127.0.0.1/- h.zip', 'rb', false);
```

Well, I got what I wanted.

But, the weird thing is, if I change `h` to `H`, like below:

```php
// That's say remote file name: "- H.zip"
fopen('http://127.0.0.1/- H.zip', 'rb', false);
```

Got 400 bad request!

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for your help, rawurlencode can fix it. But why "- H" triggers 400 error, "- h" not?

Comment: Not sure, that is strange, but you should encode anything.

Answer (score 2):

try to set an encode function like this:

```
function encodeURI($URI)
{
    return str_replace(array('%', '^', '+', '{', '[', '}', ']', '"', '|', '\\', '<', '>', ' '),
        array('%25', '%5E', '%2B', '%7B', '%5B', '%7D', '%5D', '%22', '%7C', '%5C', '%3C', '%3E', '%20'), $URI);
}
```

**and then:**

```
$url = encodeURI('http://127.0.0.1/- H.zip');
fopen($url, 'rb', false);
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081074/php-fopenurlwithwhitespaces)

Comment: Do you have any idea about why "- H" triggers 400 error, but "- h" not?