# A tool or a way to correctly encode subject and body params on mailto links?

Tags: php, email, uri, encode, subject

How to convert a link like this:

```
mailto:info@acme.com?body=Buongiorno, gradirei ricevere maggiori informazioni in merito alla possibilità di personalizzare i vostri prodotti.&subject=richiesta informazioni per personalizzazione prodotti
```

In this:

```
mailto:info@acme.com?body=Buongiorno%2C%20gradirei%20ricevere%20maggiori%20informazioni%20in%20merito%20alla%20possibilit%C3%A0%20di%20personalizzare%20i%20vostri%20prodotti%26subject%3Drichiesta%20informazioni%20per%20personalizzazione%20prodotti%0A
```

I've searched for on line tools but found nothing really useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, these are links that really do the encodeURI job:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

http://pressbin.com/tools/urlencode_urldecode/

They use the encodeURI function, and produce a string like this:

```
Buongiorno%2C%20gradirei%20ricevere%20maggiori%20informazioni%20in%20merito%20alla%20possibilit%C3%A0 etc etc....
```

While most of the online encoders would wrongly (to my needs) produce a string like this:

```
Buongiorno%2C+gradirei+ricevere+maggiori+informazioni+in+merito+alla+possibilit%C3%A0+di+personalizzare etc etc...
```

The reason why is that they use urlencode() instead of encodeURI()

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Stratboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551357/stratboy) in [his good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30861998/4074148), you have to encode your subject and body using a function encoding your link into URI (like for example the one given by [commonpike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95733/commonpike) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059053/4074148)), not just `url_encode`d:

```
<?php
function encodeURI($url) {
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI
    $unescaped = array(
        '%2D'=>'-','%5F'=>'_','%2E'=>'.','%21'=>'!', '%7E'=>'~',
        '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')'
    );
    $reserved = array(
        '%3B'=>';','%2C'=>',','%2F'=>'/','%3F'=>'?','%3A'=>':',
        '%40'=>'@','%26'=>'&','%3D'=>'=','%2B'=>'+','%24'=>'$'
    );
    $score = array(
        '%23'=>'#'
    );
    return strtr(rawurlencode($url), array_merge($reserved,$unescaped,$score));

}

$email = 'info@acme.com';
$subject = 'richiesta informazioni per personalizzazione prodotti';
$body = 'Buongiorno, gradirei ricevere maggiori informazioni in merito alla possibilità di personalizzare i vostri prodotti.';

$mailtoURI = 'mailto:'.$email.'?body='.encodeURI($body).'?subject='.encodeURI($subject);
$mailtoUrlEncode = 'mailto:'.$email.'?body='.urlencode($body).'?subject='.urlencode($subject);

echo $mailtoURI; //the good one
echo $mailtoUrlEncode; //the wrong one
```

Output of `$mailtoURI`:

> mailto:info@acme.com?body=Buongiorno,%20gradirei%20ricevere%20maggiori%20informazioni%20in%20merito%20alla%20possibilit%C3%A0%20di%20personalizzare%20i%20vostri%20prodotti.?subject=richiesta%20informazioni%20per%20personalizzazione%20prodotti

With `urlencode` (notice how space for example are not encoded, while they should, as [described in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)):

> mailto:info@acme.com?body=Buongiorno%2C+gradirei+ricevere+maggiori+informazioni+in+merito+alla+possibilit%C3%A0+di+personalizzare+i+vostri+prodotti.?subject=richiesta+informazioni+per+personalizzazione+prodotti

You can encode it directly in Javascript:

```
var email = 'info@acme.com';
var subject = 'richiesta informazioni per personalizzazione prodotti';
var body = 'Buongiorno, gradirei ricevere maggiori informazioni in merito alla possibilità di personalizzare i vostri prodotti.'

var mailto = 'mailto:' + email + '?body=' + encodeURI($body) + '?subject=' + encodeURI($subject);
console.log(mailto);
```

Or if you don't want to code it, you can use online tools like [the ones given in Stratboy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30861998/4074148).

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a slightly different version of commonpike's one:

```
  public static function encodeURI($url) {
    $unescaped = array(
        '%2D'=>'-','%5F'=>'_','%2E'=>'.','%21'=>'!', '%7E'=>'~',
        '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')'
    );
    $reserved = array(
        '%3B'=>';','%2C'=>',','%2F'=>'/','%3F'=>'?','mailto%3A'=>'mailto:',
        '%3A%2F%2F'=>'://','%40'=>'@','%26'=>'&','%3D'=>'=','%2B'=>'+','%24'=>'$'
    );
    $score = array(
        '%23'=>'#'
    );
    return strtr(rawurlencode($url), array_merge($reserved,$unescaped,$score));
  }
```

See the $reserved array:

```
'mailto%3A'=>'mailto:','%3A%2F%2F'=>'://'
```

I needed to specify them because I don't want to get back ALL the ':'. Only the ones used in protocols. For example, if I need to encode an URI containing a mail body with some ':' inside, I'll need to encode them, especially if i'm saving the uri into some serialized db field (':' likely will break something..). So, that's my version. Don't know if useful for everyone, though. But I just share.