# URL encode string the way google does in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, curl, encoding

I have an URL which I need to CURL in PHP:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q= select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "LINE" and startDate = "2015-09-23" and endDate  = "2015-09-25" &format=xml &env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

When I use the URL "as is" I get nothing, no data, blank page.

When I enter the URL in the address bar of Chrome I get some encoding and the URL looks like this:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%20select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20=%20%22LINE%22%20and%20startDate%20=%20%222015-09-23%22%20and%20endDate%20=%20%222015-09-25%22%20&format=xml%20&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

Now when I CURL this URL above it works, I get data. 
The problem is that I need to do this programmatic instead of copy/paste. So I used `rawurlencode` and `urlencode` But they don't transform the URL like above and I get a blank page once again.

What type of encoding (preferably PHP but javascript is also good) should I use to transform the URL like Google Chrome does?

Comment: _So I used rawurlencode and urlencode_ - have you applied it only on the parameters of the query string?

Comment: @Leggendario I used it on the entire URL, which did not work and then I used it on the parameters only, that also didn't work.

Comment: _I used it on the entire URL_ - It's a mistake. _then I used it on the parameters only_ - how you did that?

Comment: @Leggendario It doesn't matter. There are to many parameters, I would have to chunk it up in ten pieces or so. Im looking for a more universal method that would take the entire URL. The problem (Ithink) is that the double quotes and equal symbols are getting encoded as well, that is what is producing the problem

Comment: How can we answer to you if you say "It doesn't matter"? Let us to see how you encode your uri. You may want to use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6059053/711206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Javascript, you can use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI):

```js
document.querySelector('div').textContent = encodeURI('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q= select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "LINE" and startDate = "2015-09-23" and endDate  = "2015-09-25" &format=xml &env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys');
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much:) Any idea on how to do this in PHP?

Comment: I'm doing some research here, but I've never used php, sorry :(

Comment: @user2604269 take a look at this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929584/encodeuri-in-php - the guy who gave the answer with more votes have created a helper function in PHP with the same behavior of Javascript's `encodeURI`.