# Special characters not working in svg

Tags: php, xml, svg, xml-parsing

I have some `svg` which has some special characters in it. while parsing it into xml, getting the error. Here is the `svg`,

```
https://www.printhubpro.co.uk/images/export.svg
```

It has string like this in `svg`

```
ú (may be representing EURO)
```

Which causing issue.

I want to allow special character in `svg`.
Any suggestion?

Comment: What mime type are you serving the svg as? What encoding are you setting?

Comment: just this `<svg xml:space="preserve" viewBox="847.565 397.65 584.37 819.7" height="2480.3163" width="1748.03244" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` nothing else @RobertLongson

Comment: And how does that address my question about the mime type?

Comment: fabric js doing canvas to svg. so i dont know about that

Comment: PHP equivalent of [encodeURIComponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734250/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-in-php) resolves this.

Answer (score -1):

The SVG you are trying to load is not valid. If you visit it in Chrome it won't render that bit at all.

```
error on line 22 at column 412: Encoding error
```

[Entity encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) your special characters before including them.

Comment: Yes it because special character in it like `ú`. thats the issue, i want to allow special character in svg.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardiya You can't just dump special characters in to an SVG (effectively an XML file). You have to entity encode them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: any preferable solution?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardiya The solution is to not generate SVGs with special characters in them. You have to encode the characters properly. It is mandatory. If you don't, no SVG renderer can be expected to anything sensible with your file.

Comment: but svg is generating from canvas dynamically, as i am trying to encode using replace that text like this `$svg_op = str_replace('ú','&#xa3;',$svg_op);` is not working, but if i replace `&#xa3;` manually then its working. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardiya Try this instead: `$svg_op = str_replace("\xA3","&#xa3;",$svg_op);`

Comment: -1 for being a link-only answer.  You should include that the Euro symbol can be displayed in the document using the string `&#8364;`.