# How can i have a paragraph in my mail()

Tags: php, html

Hi im working on a button that will open a new mail tab with the predefined text but i cant have any paragraphs in the mail.
I tried \n and `<br>` nothing works...

```
$message .= '<html>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="mailto:' . $email . '?Subject=Deine Reservierung in der 73 Burger.Bar.&Body=Servus, vielen Dank fuer deine Reservierungsanfrage, hiermit bestaetigen wir deine gewueschte Reservierung am ' . $date . ' um ' . $time . ' fuer ' . $amount . '' . "\n" . ' Personen." target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #EB7035; border-top: 12px solid #EB7035; border-bottom: 12px solid #EB7035; border-right: 18px solid #EB7035; border-left: 18px solid #EB7035; display: inline-block;">Annehmen &rarr;</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </html>';
```

Comment: strongly recommend not using a mailto tag. an html form would be a better idea

Comment: could u send me a link to a description i only used mail() until now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script

Answer (score 0):

Use `\r\n` instead of `\n` or `<br>`.

Also, if you specify the mail type as HTML, then `<br>` should work.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting error messages? Have you checked your server logs?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question now: you are passing the text through a URL, so you need to use `urlencode()` to preserve the newlines.

```
$body = urlencode('Servus, vielen Dank fuer deine Reservierungsanfrage, hiermit bestaetigen wir deine gewueschte Reservierung am ' . $date . ' um ' . $time . ' fuer ' . $amount . "\n" . ' Personen.');
```

Comment: this works but i have a + for every blank.

looks like this:
Servus,+vielen+Dank+fuer+deine+Reservierungsanfrage,+hiermit+bestaetigen+wir+deine+gewueschte+Reservierung+am++um++fuer+
+Personen.

Answer (score -1):

As per RFC2368 which defines mailto:, further reinforced by an example in RFC1738, it is explicitly stated that the only valid way to generate a line break is with %0D%0A.

Please try below code,

```
$message .= '<html>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="mailto:' . $email . '?Subject=Deine Reservierung in der 73 Burger.Bar.&Body=Servus, vielen Dank fuer deine Reservierungsanfrage, hiermit bestaetigen wir deine gewueschte Reservierung am ' . $date . ' um ' . $time . ' fuer ' . $amount . '' . "%0D%0A" . ' Personen." target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #EB7035; border-top: 12px solid #EB7035; border-bottom: 12px solid #EB7035; border-right: 18px solid #EB7035; border-left: 18px solid #EB7035; display: inline-block;">Annehmen &rarr;</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </html>';
```

this question too of stackoverflow,
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524663/line-break-in-body-of-mailto-link)

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me