# How to pass a hashtag in a ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a chat that uses ajax to send messages to the server. My problem is that when the user tries to send a hashtag, everything after the hashtag is omitted. I saw a similar question like this that said encoding would help. I tried encoding it, but it created bigger problems when it got to the php. It started counting the + sign as a space and made the first two numbers after a % sign go missing. Is there a workaround to this in php, or should I try something other than encoding.

here is the relevant javascript with the encoding.

```
ajax.open("GET",   "/chatAdd.php?msg=" + encodeURIComponent(message.value) +   "&user=" + encodeURIComponent(user) + "&id=" + encodeURIComponent(id));
```

And the php i used to decode it.

```
$user = urldecode($_REQUEST["user"]);
$userID = urldecode($_REQUEST["id"]);
$msg = urldecode($_REQUEST["msg"]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of JavaScript's encodeURIcomponent in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734250/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javascripts-encodeuricomponent-in-php)

Comment: I don't think you need those calls to `urldecode`, it should be decoded automagically.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Replace the hash with %23.

Edit:  Also, a really great resource for escaping in JS and PHP - http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/

Comment: They appear to be using `encodeURIComponent` which should escape it already.