# PHP urlencode not working as intended

Tags: php, urlencode

I have a URL with space characters that I want to properly encode when making an API call (in this case replace ' ' with '%20' so the space characters are treated properly.

```
$url = 'https://www.someapi.com?param=this and that';
```

Hoever when using the urlencode($url) function I get this obscure representation of the URL

```
"https%3A%2F%2..."
```

That I eventually cannot resolve.

[image]........

Is there a URL-encode function in PHP that just replaces spaces and quotation marks instead of making abrupt changes to the whole string?

Comment: You don't want to encode the entire thing, just: `$url = 'https://www.someapi.com?param='.urlencode('this and that');`.  You're not encoding a URL you are encoding data to be used in a URL.

Comment: how is this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160197/8058753 it can encode also path.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse request url and only encode query string "values".

```
$url = "https://www.someapi.com?param=this and that";
$baseUrl = explode("?",$url)[0];
parse_str(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY),$args);
foreach ($args as $key=>&$arg){
    $arg= urlencode($arg);
} 
echo  $baseUrl."?".http_build_query($args);
```

Result:

```
https://www.someapi.com?param=this%2Band%2Bthat
```