# The overview path obtained from google directions is displayed in the wrong place on static maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api, google-directions-api

I'm getting an overview polyline from google directions between two points then pass it as "enc:" parameter to static maps.

Once the image is rendered the polyline follows the actual shape of the road but it's displaced hundred of meters or maybe one kilometer.

Markers are set to the same coords passed to directions API but markers are displayed correctly.

I also tried to set the static maps geodesic parameter to "true" but had the same problem.

See:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:green%7Clabel:A%7C21.0453333,-86.78226990000002&markers=color:red%7Clabel:B%7C21.038007,-86.869206&size=640x320&path=weight:6%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:%7Dkm_CpytpOcJTqBCyDOiAECDCF?H@FjCL%7CBFjEIL[lEQpBCv@?xAHdBN%7C@LBZBf@nBt@%7CDrBzBnAbBz@vAd@nBX~AFpACxACAJtAd@j@%5Ch@h@%5Cr@R%7C@Dv@EdAMf@s@BoCxFaErIoC%7CFOZk@t@]t@]dA[BGv@Ap@HjEHERrJHzCHz@TnA%5CfAn@rAtHjPpAtCv@xBjBnFZp@Vh@b@n@hBnBfB~B%7CLvQ~AxB@d@z@l@v@b@vAd@nCz@Ct@zBr@tAv@t@r@j@z@h@vAPv@F@DhACAKA%7B@nDQf@cJ~_@wKle@kEReDvNiLvf@[pAm@zAu@~Aa@lAIb@QxAQzBMhAm@lCoAnFcAjEGr@C%5EBdAB%5EN~@Vt@Zp@%5Ef@%7C@z@hEpD%7C@z@d@n@%5Ev@Pt@LlAAx@GlA@JC%5ECZKrBUvCUpAa@lAcAhBg@ASXOJEFsAdCe@z@aCpEoBfD%7BCjFw@zAiEnIyFtK%7BOzY%7DFzKGVoCdFYAIb@@j@FT%5Eh@zD~BzDCXD%5CFRCVUh@aAxAwCvBgDJQbC%7DEd@UVIh@IX@%5EOHBZEbAYPSLWn@kA&key=AIzaSyDdFa0XLRwG7iR24xU8849VSpV-iBWY6U0

or

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:green%7Clabel:A%7C21.038007,-86.869206&markers=color:red%7Clabel:B%7C21.0880741,-86.77087180000001&size=640x320&path=weight:6%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:o~k_CpseqOh@iA@*@IWg@*@YOWCODMNaBtCYJc@F%7BANe@Ag@E%7BBwAyCoBg@O_@o@EMCk@FWRk@nDyG~Sm@r@mABcDbBaDzKsSFY@o@z@aBp@uA%5EwALaAXeFHeAFGFw@AsBIw@Ss@[s@iA%7BAqE%7DDk@c@a@g@i@%7B@Qk@YuAGaA@u@JeAjCcL%7C@sD~@_Cb@aAJYPo@PaAPcCP%7DAP%7B@tGaYfJ%7B@b@cBz@mCxBkGZkAnAiJPeAlAuFxCqMbBoGp@%7DCh@iCd@%7BAd@_AlAkBj@cANg@Hi@d@iDr@_GHuBAw@I%7D@U_Ag@oAu@cA%7D@y@yAq@uA[cJq@oAQkAa@wAkAkTm%5C_CuDcAcBm@iAcB%7DDkG_NsBmEc@cA[kASgAIy@IcCUqIQuJDeBJy@Ny@V%7B@v@iBfA_ChDiHrFoLBaDd@gANy@AaAS%7B@OYa@g@qA%7BAc@[w@Yu@KcABaBNaAB_CMkBYiA_@mDiBmDoBwBeB_Ag@q@_@%7B@OuASmB?iIZ_JZ_GNoC?iHWkPo@%7DI]%7DBQcCG_CCuCa@%7D@QyJgBcASq@Us@[c@e@gBmBwAcBy@m@w@a@sAc@qBa@mB[*BI%7B@?y@HoAPsBXcJnAwNtBk@F*@?mAWuA_@uDcAcBi@eA_@s@]uDuBcIqEm@c@i@Uw@QsDe@eHyAsLeCcEeAqDk@cO_FoL%7DCaD%7D@oAm@gBm@iAWsAk@?OCe@Li@Pe@d@w@h@y@NU&key=AIzaSyDdFa0XLRwG7iR24xU8849VSpV-iBWY6U0](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:green%7Clabel:A%7C21.038007,-86.869206&markers=color:red%7Clabel:B%7C21.0880741,-86.77087180000001&size=640x320&path=weight:6%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:o~k_CpseqOh@iA@_@IWg@_@YOWCODMNaBtCYJc@F%7BANe@Ag@E%7BBwAyCoBg@O_@o@EMCk@FWRk@nDyG~Sm@r@mABcDbBaDzKsSFY@o@z@aBp@uA%5EwALaAXeFHeAFGFw@AsBIw@Ss@[s@iA%7BAqE%7DDk@c@a@g@i@%7B@Qk@YuAGaA@u@JeAjCcL%7C@sD~@_Cb@aAJYPo@PaAPcCP%7DAP%7B@tGaYfJ%7B@b@cBz@mCxBkGZkAnAiJPeAlAuFxCqMbBoGp@%7DCh@iCd@%7BAd@_AlAkBj@cANg@Hi@d@iDr@_GHuBAw@I%7D@U_Ag@oAu@cA%7D@y@yAq@uA[cJq@oAQkAa@wAkAkTm%5C_CuDcAcBm@iAcB%7DDkG_NsBmEc@cA[kASgAIy@IcCUqIQuJDeBJy@Ny@V%7B@v@iBfA_ChDiHrFoLBaDd@gANy@AaAS%7B@OYa@g@qA%7BAc@[w@Yu@KcABaBNaAB_CMkBYiA_@mDiBmDoBwBeB_Ag@q@_@%7B@OuASmB?iIZ_JZ_GNoC?iHWkPo@%7DI]%7DBQcCG_CCuCa@%7D@QyJgBcASq@Us@[c@e@gBmBwAcBy@m@w@a@sAc@qBa@mB[_BI%7B@?y@HoAPsBXcJnAwNtBk@F_@?mAWuA_@uDcAcBi@eA_@s@]uDuBcIqEm@c@i@Uw@QsDe@eHyAsLeCcEeAqDk@cO_FoL%7DCaD%7D@oAm@gBm@iAWsAk@?OCe@Li@Pe@d@w@h@y@NU&key=AIzaSyDdFa0XLRwG7iR24xU8849VSpV-iBWY6U0)

I'm sending the final Static Maps URL through an email.

Comment: What does the original poly line from the directions service look like (or what is the request you made to obtain it)?

Comment: @geocodezip https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=21.038007,-86.869206&destination=21.0880741,-86.77087180000001&key=AIzaSyDdFa0XLRwG7iR24xU8849VSpV-iBWY6U0

Comment: @geocodezip for both cases: case 1: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=21.0453333,-86.78226990000002&destination=21.038007,-86.869206&key=AIzaSyDdFa0XLRwG7iR24xU8849VSpV-iBWY6U0                                                                                          case 2:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=21.038007,-86.869206&destination=21.0880741,-86.77087180000001&key=AIzaSyDdFa0XLRwG7iR24xU8849VSpV-iBWY6U0    With that you get a json, and I take the "overview_polyline" -> "points" string

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

The problem:

Obtained "overview_polyline" from Google Directions JSON response contained a lot of special characters that were bad escaped once the URL pass through the mail server.

I concatenate the static maps url with the "overview_path" in PHP, so to make sure all characters were well escaped I used the ***rawurlencode*** function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1734255/7441808):

```
$revert = array('%21'=>'!', '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')');
$wellEscapedString = strtr( rawurlencode($original_string), $revert );
```

Now the line matches perfect to the road.